# Client Statistics in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, ssms, business-intelligence

Is it possible to check Client Statistics (Include Client Statistics in MS) for SSIS query (Data Flow)? I wonder if it possible to catch these information using any DMV.

I use SQL Server 2008R2.

Comment: SSIS already collects a lot of statistics for each step, which you can view from an Execution Report. These are stored in SSISDB for historical comparisons. What are you looking for? Client Statistics is a feature of SSMS anyway and doesn't make much sense for SSIS where the data is *not* read at once but streamed according to settings, buffering etc.

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been to tune the queries prior to making an SSIS package. You can also tune the SSIS package after creating it (one example: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-integration-services/designing-ssis-packages-high-performance).

In answer to your question though, I do not believe that you can capture the client stats within SSIS. A Profile trace or Extended Events might give you some good information though.